# Scan an array of pointers using pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

This is an **example** to how check the dimension of an array of `char` pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){

    // prototype
    int checkDim( char **array);

    char *days[] = {      //array of pointers
        "Sunday",         //days[0] = {'S','u','n','d','a','y','\0'}
        "Monday",         //days[1] = {....}
        "Tuesday",        //days[2] = {....}
        "Wednesday",      //days[3] = {....}
        "Thursday",       //days[4] = {....}
        "Friday",         //days[5] = {....}
        "Saturday"        //days[6] = {....}
    };

    int dim;
    dim = checkDim( days );

    printf("Number of days = %i \n", dim );

    return 0;
}

int checkDim(  char **array ){

    char **ptr = array;

    while(*ptr){
        ++ptr;
    }

    return ptr - array;
}
```

Respectively:

`days[0]` is a pointer to char (another array),
`days[1]` is a pointer to char (another array)
...
`days[i]` is a pointer to char (another array)

With a `while` I can scan the array containing the pointers:

```
char **ptr = array; //

while(*ptr){
    ++ptr;
}
```

### How I can can stop on the first element `days[0]` and scan every letter to check the length of `days[0]` (subsequently `days[1]`, `days[2]` etc...)?

I would like a `printf` like this (for example):

`> Number of days 7.`

`> Sunday is long 6 letters`

`> Monday is long 6 letters`

`> Tuesday is long 7 letters`

etc..

Comment: Your code's behavior is undefined, it accesses out-of-bounds. Not all arrays are NULL-terminated the way strings are.

Comment: `"Saturday"` --> `"Saturday", NULL`

Comment: Note that weeks start on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all:

`checkDim()` as it stands invokes undefined behaviour by accessing the pointer array `days` out of bounds when looping past the pointer for `"Saturday"`.

It's just bad luck the code seems to run.

To fix this do explicitly introduce a `NULL` value at the end of `days` to functions as a sentinel:

```
  char * days[] = {      //array of pointers
    "Sunday",         //days[0] = {'S','u','n','d','a','y','\0'}
    ...
    "Saturday",        //days[6] = {....}
    NULL
  };
```

---

To answer your question:

To print the length of each "string" during iteration you code do this:

```
  while (*ptr)
  {
    printf("'%s' has length %zu.\n", *ptr, strlen(*ptr));
    ++ptr;
  }
```

Please note that `strlen()` returns `size_t` (not `int`) to using the conversion specifiers `d` or `u` is wrong here. If `zu` is not defined by the compiler in use (VC) you want to use `lu` instead.

---

Two more things:

1. Placement of prototypes

   Prototypes should be at global scope.

   So change this:

   ```
   int main(void)
   {
     // prototype
     int checkDim( char **array);
   ```

   to be:

   ```
   // prototype
   int checkDim( char ** array);

   int main(void)
   {
   ```
2. Qualify argument staying constant as `const`

   `checkDim` does not change `days`, so help the compiler to create the best code by telling this to it.

   Change this:

   ```
   int checkDim(char **array)
   ```

   to be:

   ```
   int checkDim(const char ** array)
   ```